# Using Functions In C

Tags: c

I'm running into an error when I try to scan the value entered into income, what's wrong with this code? I think it has something to do with using income twice, I could simply change the name of the variable, is their another way to solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float TaxDue(float income){
    float tax = 0;

    if (income < 0){
        printf("\nYou've Enter A Negative Income");
    }
    else if (income <= 750){
        tax = (income * .01);
    }
    else if (income <= 2250){
        tax = 7.50 + ((income - 750) * .02);
    }
    else if (income <= 3750){
        tax = 37.50 + ((income - 2250) * .03);
    }
    else if (income <= 5250){
        tax = 82.50 + ((income - 3750) * .04);
    }
    else if (income <= 7000){
        tax = 142.50 + ((income - 5250) * .05);
    }
    else if (income > 7000){
        tax = 230.00 + ((income - 7000) * .06);
    }
    else{
        printf("\nError");
    }

    return tax;
}

int main(void){
    float income = 0;

    printf("Enter Your Taxable Income: ");
    scanf("%f", income);
    printf("\nYou Owe %f In Taxes", TaxDue(income));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is in the scanf(). You need to pass in the address of income (i.e., &income).

Comment: `scanf("%f", &income);` passes the correct pointer to `scanf()`.  Don't forget to check the return value to be sure you got a number.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem, I thought it was a bigger issue than that, thanks.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  GCC will warn about such errors, at least if you use warning options such as `-Wall`.  If your compiler was producing any warnings, you should heed what it says; remember, it knows a lot more about C than you do at the moment.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, I'm at school right now, and it gave me this response but I didn't know what it meant. "Unhandled exception at 0x54FE96AA (msvcr120d.dll) in Chapter 9 Project 2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

Comment: Access violation means you tried to use a pointer that was not pointing somewhere valid.  The 0x00000000 means you're compiling for 32-bit hardware, and you are accessing a null pointer.

Comment: Note, too, that it is best to _end_ messages with a newline rather than _start_ them with a newline.  At least, the trailing newline maximizes your chance of seeing the messages in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following statement in main:

```
scanf("%f", income);
```

as

```
scanf("%f", &income);
```